# Accumulating integration problem - help me to understand

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Here is the problem stem:

A factory produces bicycles at the rate of $ p(w) = 95 + 0.1w^2 - w$ bikes per week for $0 \le w \le 25$.

The factory ships bicycles out at a rate of $s(w)= 90 $ for $0\le w\lt3$  and at a rate of $s(w)=95$ for $3\le w\le25$.

Now the actual questions, and my work:

(1) How many bikes are produced in the first 2 weeks?

My answer: $ \int_0^2 p(w) \ dw$ = about 188

(2) How many bikes are in the warehouse at the end of week 3?

My answer: $ \int_0^3 p(w) \ dw \ \ - \int_0^3 90 \ dw$ = about 11

(3)  Find when the number of bikes in the warehouse is at a minimum.

Here is the first place I am stuck.  I don't know how to deal with the fact that the rate of shipping is changing over the interval.  It's 90 bikes/week for the first three weeks, but 95 bikes/week the rest of the time.

I figured that I would write a function for the number of bikes in the warehouse, and then differentiate it, find critical points, check endpoints, etc.

$ b(t)=\int_0^t p(w) \ dw  \ \ - \ \ \int_0^t 90 \ dw $  should be the number of bikes in the warehouse during the first t weeks, yes?  Where t is between 0 and 3.

And $ b(t)=\int_3^t p(w) \ dw  \ \ - \ \ \int_3^t 95 \ dw $ should be the number of bikes in the warehouse during t weeks where t is between 3 and 25.

Is this correct?  I should be splitting the interval and taking 2 derivatives separately, finding critical points on each and checking endpoints for each?  I got that there are no critical points from 0 to 3.  From 3 to 25, I got critical numbers at 0 and 10.  Checking these and the endpoints meant that t=0 with 0 bikes must be the minimum.  The answer key had this, but it said nothing about breaking the interval into two pieces, so I don't know if there was an easier way to do this.

Finally, (4):  The factory needs to stop production if the number of bikes in the warehouse reaches 20 or more.  Does this happen at any time during the 25 weeks?  If so, when?

Ok, so here I reasoned that since I already know that there were 11 bikes in the warehouse at the end of week 3, then I just need to calculate if and when during the second part of the interval from 3 to 25 weeks (where the shipping rate is 95 bikes/week) the number of bikes in the warehouse ever reaches 9.  That is, the initial value is 11, and so I figured:

$ b(t)=11+\int_3^t p(w) \ dw  \ \ - \ \ \int_3^t 95 \ dw $

Since I am trying to see if b(t) ever hits 20, then it would follow that

$ 9=\int_3^t p(w) \ dw  \ \ - \ \ \int_3^t 95 \ dw $ = $\int_3^t (.1w^2-w) \ dw $ = $ 0.0333t^3 - .5t^2 + 3.6 $

This solves to $t = 15.661$ weeks.

I figured this was correct until the answer key said no, it's supposed to be 6.304 weeks.

I would appreciate any help in understanding the problem and what I did wrong.

Comment: I cannot see that you made a mistake. 6.304 weeks cannot be the correct answer. There are 11 bikes at the end of week 3. After that, the shipping rate is greater than the production rate until week 10. So the number of bikes in stock is decreasing from week 3 to week 10 and cannot hit 20 in this time period. Answer key must be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, Max.  I think what confused me about my breaking of the integral was that when I tried to figure how many bikes were in the warehouse at, say, t=10, I got a negative number.  I figured that must have meant I did it wrong somewhere.  But it could be that it just means the warehouse was empty until later in the interval, when, as you said, production outstrips shipping.  Thanks for your help.